# Recomendation for Gamepad

Tags: gaming

Can I ask for advice on a USB wired Gamepad, have been looking at Speedlink RAIT which seems to be reasonable quality for the price.  Willing to spend say £25 on one but £50 seems a bit excessive for what I am going to use it for.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Hardware Recommendations! Can you clarify what your requirements are for the gamepad? Typically Xbox/Playstation controllers tend to be affordable and high-quality; if there's something more specialized that you need, let us know.

Comment: Just a basic XInput gamepad, prefferably of respectable quality, noot absolute chinese tat.  Hoowever, it won't be used enough to justify paying a premium price.  At the moment I don't know one from another.

Comment: I'd probably pick either an Xbox or Playstation controller up used then, it should be less than £25.